# Storing expensive database calculations in Microsoft SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I'm Using Microsoft SQL Server. I want to store/cache expensive calculations so they can be reused. In my example I have items that are rated by users, the database schema looks like this:

```
User
 Id : int

Item
 Id : int

UserItemRating
 UserId (User)
 ItemId (Item)
 Rating : int
```

To get the highest rated items I need to calculate the average rating of each item (lets assume the operation is expensive and that UserItemRating is changed/updated frequently). What is a good way of caching this calculation? Should I add a column "AverageRating" to Item and create a trigger that updates it? Create a view? A temporary table that holds the calculations?

Comment: The "go to" solution is "don't store data that you can easily calculate", with the added proviso of "unless the performance of re-calculating the data is prohibitive".

Comment: If you do decide to store the calculated answers, the best solution is (if possible) go with the solution which your database system natively supports for storing calculated data (e.g. indexed or materialized views) - but for more info on that, we'd need to know what RDBMS you're using.

Comment: Thanks. Changed the wording of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, you would create an indexed view, something like this:

```
create view dbo.ItemRatings
with schemabinding
as
    select
        ItemId,
        COUNT_BIG(*) as Cnt,
        SUM(Rating) as TotalRating
    from
        dbo.UserItemRating
    group by
        ItemId
go
create unique clustered index IX_ItemRatings on dbo.ItemRatings (ItemId)
```

There are various [restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx#Restrictions) on the creation and usage of indexed views, but the above is valid (assuming `UserItemRating` is in the `dbo` schema).

Things to note:

1. has to be `WITH SCHEMABINDING`, which in turn means that we have to use two-part names to reference the table(s).
2. has to use `COUNT_BIG()` in order to be able to use a `GROUP BY` clause
3. Doesn't directly contain the average (indeed, `AVG` isn't allowed in indexed views), however, you can compute it by dividing the `SUM()` by the `COUNT_BIG()`.
4. To make use of the index on this view, you either need to query it with the `NOEXPAND` hint, or be running Enterprise Edition or better.

Why is this preferred over a trigger/table based solution? Because the code to perform the maintenance is *built in* to SQL Server, and will have a lower overall overhead than any other solution. (And you don't have to spend time making sure it's *correct*)

If you are using Enterprise Edition, it can even make use of this indexed view without your query directly referencing it - such as if you were to make a query against the base table that asked for the `COUNT`, `SUM`, or even the `AVG`, it might use this index.